# SSH for root User on Private - but publicly accessable - machine

Tags: ssh, security, root, hosting

It is probably a duplicate of any question I did not find, but I am curious.

I own a Linux - server hosted somewhere and I configured it to allow ssh connections for user root - actually it has no other real user configured. It has no password all together and `sshd` is configured to allow password-less root login.

- I also saw several posts saying root-password combinations are to easy to guess and you should therefore disable remote root login. Further on they usually write ssh keys are nearly unguessable and therefore considered save. So why should no one use them on root then?
- Sometimes they state something like you see who does something on your system, but it is my own private system, if someone else does something there with out me knowing I am in big trouble never the less, right? I get it for non private systems, but nothing like mine.
- And finally they even write you could extinguish what command needs to have root privileges and which do not. I think having a program you do not trust making no unexpected things on your system is the real security issue here. Or it is just you yourself and you better have backup then...

So what is the real reason everyone should ban root login from ssh all together? Is it outdated or is my use-case a niche one that is just overseen or am I wrong and overseeing any issues here?

Well I am well aware my security lies in the ssh key I am using and therefore I restrict myself from letting a key leave the client disk in any matter. So in case I lose my phone, I just remove this line in my `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

---

My configuration before someone asks...:

/etc/passwd

```
root:x:0:0::/root:/bin/bash
bin:x:1:1::/:/usr/bin/nologin
daemon:x:2:2::/:/usr/bin/nologin
mail:x:8:12::/var/spool/mail:/usr/bin/nologin
ftp:x:14:11::/srv/ftp:/usr/bin/nologin
http:x:33:33::/srv/http:/usr/bin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:Nobody:/:/usr/bin/nologin
dbus:x:81:81:System Message Bus:/:/usr/bin/nologin
systemd-journal-remote:x:982:982:systemd Journal Remote:/:/usr/bin/nologin
systemd-network:x:981:981:systemd Network Management:/:/usr/bin/nologin
systemd-resolve:x:980:980:systemd Resolver:/:/usr/bin/nologin
systemd-timesync:x:979:979:systemd Time Synchronization:/:/usr/bin/nologin
systemd-coredump:x:978:978:systemd Core Dumper:/:/usr/bin/nologin
uuidd:x:68:68::/:/usr/bin/nologin
git:x:976:976:git daemon user:/:/usr/bin/git-shell
polkitd:x:102:102:PolicyKit daemon:/:/usr/bin/nologin
dnsmasq:x:974:974:dnsmasq daemon:/:/usr/bin/nologin
named:x:40:40:BIND DNS Server:/:/usr/bin/nologin
systemd-oom:x:972:972:systemd Userspace OOM Killer:/:/usr/bin/nologin
```

/etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server
```

/etc/shadow

```
root:*:14871::::::
bin:!*:18502::::::
daemon:!*:18502::::::
mail:!*:18502::::::
ftp:!*:18502::::::
http:!*:18502::::::
nobody:!*:18502::::::
dbus:!*:18502::::::
systemd-journal-remote:!*:18502::::::
systemd-network:!*:18502::::::
systemd-resolve:!*:18502::::::
systemd-timesync:!*:18502::::::
systemd-coredump:!*:18502::::::
uuidd:!*:18502::::::
git:!*:18512::::::
polkitd:!*:18522::::::
dnsmasq:!*:18522::::::
named:!*:18525::::::
systemd-oom:!*:18724::::::
```

Comment: "So why should no one use them on root then?" - Certificate is only as secure as the key size.  The recommended key size  depends on the computational capabilities at any given time.  2046 use to be the suggested size a few years ago but today it's closer to 4096.  As to the reason root should not be accessible is due to the fact root can literally do anything on the system.  The most secure method is to provide sudo access to the user, and only use root, when it's required.

Comment: yeah, the key size does matter - I forgot writing about these and I appreciate you mention the commonly considered secure sizes of `rsa` keys nowadays.  I gonna block my last 2046 key within the next few days. I got some `ed25519` keys, they are still considered secure, aren't they? About your second part, it is exactly what I wrote in my third bullet.

@DavidPostill thank you for correcting my post!